# Mysql 'err 1111 Invalid use of group function'

Tags: mysql, database

I'm getting the error:

> "[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function" for this query:

```
SELECT u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type, 
count(distinct(u.id)), 
sum(if(u.date=bp.date,sum(bp.o_outcome),0), 
sum(if(u.date=bp.date,1,0)) as P_n,
count(distinct(if(u.date=bp.date,bp.user_id,0))) 
FROM mayadata.users u 
left join mayadata.billing_pays bp
on u.id=bp.user_id
WHERE (u.date)=5 and year(u.date)=2011 and truncate(monthtimestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7
GROUP BY u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type
```

Comment: If i copy your Statement and try to run it, i got a syntaxerror

Comment: My bad. This correct:
SELECT u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type, 
count(distinct(u.id)),
sum(if(u.date=bp.date,sum(bp.o_outcome),0)), 
sum(if(u.date=bp.date,1,0)) as P_n,
count(distinct(if(u.date=bp.date,bp.user_id,0))) 
FROM mayadata.users u 
left join mayadata.billing_pays bp
on u.id=bp.user_id
WHERE (u.date)=5 and year(u.date)=2011 and truncate(monthtimestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7
GROUP BY u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: You have a `SUM` within a `SUM`. That's invalid. What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: @MarioTrucco It appears the second SUM is within an if statement

Comment: I don't know if that was typo but you missed [**,**] after `count(distinct(u.id)) `, and `sum(if(u.date=bp.date,sum(bp.o_outcome),0)) ` and you you don't need *one* tilda in `u.des_type`

Comment: sntx edited, problem stay as before:(

Comment: @Matt well, a `SUM` within an `IF` within a `SUM`, stil invalid. I really think that we need to know what the OP wants to do in order to answer

Comment: pls check my new answer below:(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING`

```
SELECT u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(u.id)) 
SUM(if(u.date = bp.date, SUM(bp.o_outcome),0)) SUM(if(u.date = bp.date,1,0)) AS P_n,
COUNT(DISTINCT(if(u.date = bp.date, bp.user_id,0))) 
FROM mayadata.users u 
LEFT JOIN mayadata.billing_pays bp ON u.id = bp.user_id
GROUP BY u.date, u.des_channel, u.des_type
HAVING (u.date) = 5 
AND year(u.date) = 2011 
AND truncate(monthtimestampdiff(hour,u.datetime,bp.datetime)/24,0)<7
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the use of a `SUM` within a `SUM` in

```
sum(if(u.date=bp.date,sum(bp.o_outcome),0)
```

which is illegal